# Can I omit fields when deserializing a JSON object?

Tags: .net, json, exception, deserialization

Using .NET's `DataContractJsonSerializer`, I am trying to deserialize a JSON object into a class I defined.
However, the object I'm deserializing has more fields than I need.
Is there a way to make it only deserialize the fields I specified in my corresponding class?
I'm trying to avoid this `SerializationException`:

> The data contract type 'xxx' cannot be deserialized because the required data member 'yyy' was not found.

Comment: Maybe use a [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) instead and make your own [`JavaScriptConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx)? (Unless the DataContractJsonSerializer has the same ability to specify a deserialization implementation...)

Comment: Indeed, the class [does have a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.datacontractsurrogate.aspx) using [`IDataContractSurrogate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I fix most of my JSON errors in .NET. I use JSON.NET instead of the built-in one.

http://json.codeplex.com/

Here's a quick example shamelessly taken from their docs:

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "\/Date(1230375600000+1300)\/",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might want a take a look at implementing [IExtensibleDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx) on your objects, along with enabling [ignoreExtensionDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.ignoreextensiondataobject.aspx).  The ignoreExtensionDataObject property specifies whether unknown data is ignored on deserialization.